# What is Tor and is there anything I can do to stop it?

Tags: tor

My teen figured out ways to get around the router firewall by using Tor. I am concerned this has opened us up to hackers, spying, and other bad stuff.

Is there any way I can block Tor from being used on our home PC or network?

Comment: As an aside TOR is really used to prevent spying rather then the other way around (though not necessarily successfully), but unless all his/hers devices are nonmobile (i.e. he/she only has access to the net from your home and has no laptop, smart phone etc.) you've been exposed to all the bad effects of someone figuring how to bypass your firewall going out pretty much always.

Comment: Tor has nothing to do with your firewall.

Comment: Get around the router firewall? What does this mean? What are the rules he/she can bypass with TOR? If it is a parental filter then you should definitely control the way he/she uses the internet. Otherwise ask him/her why the need for TOR and judge properly. And, in the end, if your teen is in the early teens (and so you don't judge him/her responsible enough) you should watch what he/she is doing on the internet, otherwise trust what he/she is doing and make him/her face the consequences.

Comment: Hi. I noticed your question was transferred here. We are going to need a few more details. You mention TOR, how is TOR involved (you can't "stop TOR", by the way)? What do you mean by "ways to get around the router firewall"? We need symptoms and technical details, as you understand them.

Comment: If anything, your kids are actually safer with TOR...

Comment: I am a mod on Parenting. There were 4 votes to close over there, so yes migration was an option to keep it from being closed.

Comment: @RoryAlsop funny you should say that ... I would almost recommend migrating this to parenting ...

Comment: @TSar I wish I could upvote that comment more than once.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev That would be partially my fault for suggesting it but given the very nice answers here I'd say it's a good fit.

Comment: @TSar Depends what you mean by safer. TOR allows access to the Hidden Wiki, which may contain direct links to illegal content.

Answer (score 10):

Using tor has not opened you up to "hackers, spying and very bad stuff," so be aware that is irrelevant. If that is what you are worried about then you need to do nothing.

Tor is a way to preserve privacy from intrusive regimes by bouncing your connection through multiple encrypted hops in a way that makes it very difficult to trace.

If your question is around how you monitor your child's activity online, then tor doesn't really change the landscape for you here either. They could hide traffic from you very easily if they are even slightly tech savvy and have admin control of their own machine. The usual solutions involve more practical things, such as asking them to use the computer in a public space, rather than the privacy of their bedroom, talking through activity with them, and general trust.

There are more technical controls, but they require managing their machine yourself, and removing their admin rights to it.

Comment: Perhaps a detail to touch on would be that TOR does provide exclusive access to illicit websites, however useful it can be.

Comment: `intrusive regimes` read parents

Comment: If your kid knows how to use Tor ... then they will easily learn they can bypass any admin restrictions on the computer itself with a bootable copy of linux.  Even if you disable boot from CD / Thumb drive ... they can easily get a secondary SATA hard drive and boot off that.

Comment: Nah. Tor is usable by non-technical folks. Part of the design remit was to make it easy

Comment: The only show that I've seen that showed TOR being used was house of cards, and the journalist using it there didn't have anything nice happen to him because of it. Maybe that was psyops but I wouldn't let anyone use TOR unsupervised from my house.

Answer (score 3):

### What is Tor

Tor "[The Onion Router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network))" is:

> free software for enabling anonymous communication. The name is
>   derived from an acronym for the original software project name "The
>   Onion Router". Tor directs Internet traffic through a free,
>   worldwide, volunteer network consisting of more than seven thousand
>   relays to conceal a user's location and usage from anyone
>   conducting network surveillance or traffic analysis. Using Tor makes
>   it more difficult for Internet activity to be traced back to the user:
>   this includes "visits to Web sites, online posts, instant messages,
>   and other communication forms". Tor's use is intended to protect
>   the personal privacy of users, as well as their freedom and ability to
>   conduct confidential communication by keeping their Internet
>   activities from being monitored.

This description, while accurate, is not incredibly useful for people who dont understand the foundations of how the Internet works ... so let me try and create an analogy that will help you better understand what is taking place.

Imagine for a moment that your child is sending an email from Jim@home.com to Billy@school.net.  This message would attempt to find the shortest path between the computer that sent the email and the computer that it is destined for.

However, lets pretend for sake of argument you dislike your kids friend and set a rule in your firewall (more likely the router) that messages destined for Billy@school.net get thrown away.  This works great at preventing Jim@home.com from talking with Billy@school.net.

But kids have this nasty habit of learning new things, and your kid discoverers that he can find 3 more random kids on the internet that are also having there messages blocked by there parents ... they all agree that if they receive a message that is from one of these other people and not specifically addressed to them they will send it to that person on behalf of the original sender.  For example:

- Jim@home.com sends a message to Sally@home.com ... and asks Sally@home.com to forward the message to Billy@school.net
- Sally@home.com sends the message to Billy@school.net
- Billy@school.net reply by sending his message to Sara@home.com and asks Sara@home.com to forward the message to Jim@home.com

This message passing setup completely bypasses the rule you put in your router to block Jim@home.com from sending messages to Billy@school.net

This is a VERY simplified example of how the Tor network works.  A message is generated by your kid and sent to random other users on the network who then send it to other random users on the network ... and after multiple transfers it eventually gets to its destination.

The message itself is encrypted so that the only people who can read the message are the person sending the message and the last person in the network before the message is sent to its destination (the exit node).

Since there are thousands of people participating in this network ... you can not realistically block the messages itself with out the use of a [white list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) which will block ALL traffic to places that you do not explicitly allow.  Setting up a white list can be very tedious as there are a great number of websites that are just fine and specifically listing each one is the equivalent of listing off the hundreds of kids at school that are good instead of simply telling your child to stay away from the handful of kids that are bad.

### Is there anything I can do to stop it?

The easiest way to stop it, is simply take away your child's internet privileges.  This may sound harsh, but if your child is a minor ... you are legally responsible for making sure they do not break the law.  Being ignorant of what your child is doing is not an excuse, and you can and will be prosecuted if your child breaks the law even if you are not knowledgeable of what they are doing.

At its best, Tor can be used to circumvent governments that attempt to suppress things like freedom of press.  At its worst it can be used to hide the communication of criminals from law enforcement agencies.

If my child was using Tor to bypass the internet restrictions I had setup ... they would be summarily grounded.  And if/when they got their internet/computer privileges back, I would monitor there usage MUCH more closely then before.  Monitoring can be done via multiple methods, but the easiest and most effective is to put the computer they are using in the middle of the common area so everyone in the household can see what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the original post came from Parenting, I can understand you are a parent that's concerned about the internet access of your teen, and you'd like to understand more about Tor.

First I would recommend searching about Tor online for what it's meant for. To simplify it as much as I can because i want to bring back the focus to parenting, the tool you've discovered your teen was using is the gateway to the dark web. It knows no censorship and restrictions, which is why it allows your teen to access websites she/he wasn't allowed to visit before.

What you're experiencing here is not a technology problem but a human problem. There will be only one way to resolve that with your child, and it's using the same methods as you'd try to dissuade your teen not to take drugs, for example. It might work, or might not work, but as a parent, I strongly suggest you sit down with your teen and discuss about it. Don't be worried, just have a common sense discussion with him/her.

In any case, that post should be sent back to Parenting if you ask me.

Answer (score -1):

I can't help noticing that existing answers describe Tor as a tool to protect one's freedom from oppressive regimes. While this was the original idea, Tor has grown much larger than that and became part of [darknet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darknet) where many illegal sites are hosted. These include **illegal drug and firearm trade, stolen credit card information, prostitution services and the like**, and are in no way suitable for teenagers. Your kid can get both you and himself in deep trouble if he's not careful. So you should be worried.

The most effective way to prevent your kid from using Tor is to **have full control over computers which have Internet connection**. You should be the only person allowed to install software on these computers. If your kid is tech-savvy and you can't trust that he will voluntarily stop using Tor after you talk to him, this will likely mean that you have to supervise him while he's online.